# R plotly: how can i set legend orientation for a second legendgroup?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I know I can set the legend orientation of a plotly plot with `layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h'))`.  However, if I include a second legendgroup in the plot, how can i also set the orientation of that one to horizontal.  Here's a simple example.  You can see the first legendgroup is horizontal but the second is vertical.  Thanks!

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)


d1 <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(1,10), 2), 
                 y = runif(20), 
                 n = c(rep("Entry 1", 10), rep("Entry 2", 10)))
d2 <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(1,10), 4), 
                 y = runif(40), 
                 n = c(rep("Entry A", 10), rep("Entry B", 10),
                       rep("Entry C", 10), rep("Entry D", 10)))

p <- plot_ly()

p <- p %>%
  add_trace(data = d1, type = "scatter", mode = "lines",
            x = ~x, y = ~y, name = ~n)

p <- p %>%
  add_trace(data = d2, type = "bar",
            x = ~x, y = ~y, name = ~n, 
            legendgroup = "group2")

p <- p %>%
  layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h'))
p
```

[image: legends]

Comment: If you remove `legendgroup = "group2"` you will see the orientation is as expected. (The colors are awful, though!) `Plotly` stacks legend groups whether you want them to or not.

Comment: Here is an [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4394) regarding this for plotly.js. There is not much you can do right now - Either you don't use legendgroups at all (as @Kat suggests) or you add another legendgroup for your first `add_trace` call to have a more consistent layout.

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal - didn't realize there was an open issue already!  I guess I'll have to just wait it out and drop the legendgroup for now as Kat suggests.